# Hibernate + Spring Data - proxy or real object?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Ok, maybe a noob question but I'm a bit confused about when Hibernate returns the real object and when its proxy, example - I use JpaRepository and its `save()` method seems to return the object itself, meaning that all the lazy collections are null. 
So, is there a) some rule to determine whether the method of repository would return entity or proxy, and b) should I always check collections for null in the code?

UPD: did some debugging, in current transaction even `repository.getOne(id)` returns the object itself, meanwhile when I enter id of the object which had been stored in DB earlier I get the proxy, as I would expect. now I'm even more puzzled :) 
 `saveAndFlush()` changes nothing

UPD2: code example, hope that helps

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = true, insertable=false)
private String dbGeneratedField;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "myEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<OtherEntity> otherEntities;

//getters, setters and stuff

}

// service method
@Transactional
public createMyEntity() {  
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
// set some necessary fields but not id

MyEntity e1 = myEntityRepository.save(entity);
return e1;
}

// repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {}
```

so, my expectation that `e1` should be either proxy or fully initialized object (meaning that collections are not null), instead of it I get the reference to `entity` object. When after save was called (suppose it received id=111) I call `repository.findOne(111)` I again get the same reference, though, when I enter this method next time (other transaction, saving another entity) and perform `repository.findOne(111)` it returns the proxy as I'd expect it from beginning.

Comment: How do you mean lazy collections are null? Actually, they are not. They are a special collection implementation instances (PersistentSet, PersistentCollection). The whole proxy thing should be transparent from usage perspective. Of course for performance reasons, it's good to know what's happening. Please be more accurate about your question as this is too wide.

Comment: @galovics, yes, it is exactly what I expected to see.. but - when I call `jpaRepository.save()` it returns the object itself, not the proxy, e. g. `jpaRepository.save(myEntity) instanceof org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy` returns `false`.

Comment: You seem to think all managed entities are proxied by Hibernate. That's not the case. A proxy is only used by Hibernate when there is a lazy toOne association, or when using getReference() to get a reference to an entity. Otherwise, queries and entity manager methods return non-proxied managed entities. What you seem to miss is that, if you create an object yourself and associate it with the persistence context, hibernate won't replace it by another object. It will use your object, as is. It's your responsibility to initialize collections of the objects you create. For more help, post example.

Comment: @JBNizet, I added code example (simplified for brevity), hope that helps to understand what's going on there. I understand that proxy is *not* always used but what is confusing me that in one case I get the object and in other I get the proxy with correct lazy collection (I'm talking about `findOne()` now)

Comment: What you get is perfectly normal and expected. You shouldn't initialize the collections to null, but to empty collections.

Comment: @JBNizet would you be so kind to explain why is this normal? The javadoc for the `save()` method states exactly the opposite: `Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely` meaning that I should obtain *updated* object, leaving collections aside, at least it means that the field `dbGeneratedField` should be updated with the value from DB. and regarding the collections - doesn't it look strange to you that the same method (`findOne()`) in one case returns the object itself and in another - proxy?

Comment: First, you need to forget about the idea that a managed entity is always a proxy. It's not, most of the time. Second, the doc says: "might have changed". You read it as "always changes", but that's wrong. save() calls [EntityManager.persist()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-) if the entity is new, and EntityManager.persist() makes the passed entity instance managed. Note BTW that persist() returns void. persist() also does not give any guarantee that the ID (and other generated columns) have been generated.

Comment: Finally, findOne() always returns the managed entity that is currently cached in the first-level cache (the hibernate session) when it's in the cache. Otherwise, it loads it from the database and stores it in the cache. persist() makes the entity managed, so persist() adds the entity to the cache, as is.

Comment: thanks @JBNizet, it's much clearer now. Though I didn't expect managed entity be always a proxy I indeed thought that it will reflect DB state at current transaction. Considering all what you've said what is the best way to get the object reflecting the latest DB state (e.g. with the generated values)?

Comment: 1. initialize your collections properly to empty collections in the entity instead of leaving them null; 2. call flush().

Comment: Tried that, as I already written in description. Despite I get an instance of proxy both collection and generated field are null and proxy doesn't run any requests to DB when I call getters.